# Dynamically populate list of states in top file

Tags: salt-stack

I am doing something like following in TOP file:

```
'roles:*database*':
    - match: grain
    - {{ salt['pillar.get']("server:database:states") }}
```

And in pillar the states are defined based on role:

```
server:
  database:
    states:
      - module1.applySecPatch
      - module2.firewallRules
```

I don't get an error and there is not helpful logging too at TRACE level. Is this the right way to populate the state file list dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is actually answered by Seth House on Salt-users group, just posting here for benefit of others*

The syntax is not quite right.

```
 'roles:*database*': 
    - match: grain 
    - {{ salt['pillar.get']("server:database:states") }}
```

Will produce something incorrect like:

```
 'roles:*database*': 
    - match: grain 
    - ['module1.applySecPatch', 'module2.firewallRules']
```

You need a loop. Something more like this:

```
'roles:*database*': 
    - match: grain 
    {% for file in salt['pillar.get']("server:database:states") %} 
    - {{ file }} 
    {% endfor %}
```